# mysql right join and conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In the following query I'm doing the join of a table calendar and a second table where I need to specify some parameters to the query.

The join of the tables is performed on the field calendar.datefield and store_product.created

The problem is that I'm filtering by id_store = 3 and another row in 07/20/2012 store_product table record has id_store = 4 and thus the query does not bring the result. Is there any way to show this result as NULL, forcing mysql to ignore this case?

Result: (the row containing the date 2012-07-20 is not being displayed because it has other id_store)

```
DATE            price
2012-07-17      NULL
2012-07-18      700.00
2012-07-19      NULL
2012-07-21      NULL
2012-07-22      NULL
2012-07-23      NULL
```

I would like to display

```
     DATE               price
     2012-07-17         NULL
     2012-07-18         700.00
     2012-07-19         NULL
->>> 2012-07-20         NULL
     2012-07-21         NULL
     2012-07-22         NULL
     2012-07-23         NULL
```

The query:

```
set @id_store = 3;
set @id_product = 11;

SELECT 
calendar.datefield as DATE,
t1.price
FROM
store_product t1
    RIGHT JOIN
calendar ON (DATE(t1.created) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE
(calendar.datefield BETWEEN ('2012-07-17') and ('2012-07-23'))
    AND (t1.id_store = @id_store OR t1.id_store is NULL)
    AND (t1.id_product = @id_product OR t1.id_product is NULL)
    AND (t1.created = (select 
        max(f2.created)
    from
        store_product f2
    where
        f2.id_store = t1.id_store
            and f2.id_product = t1.id_product
            and DATE(t1.created) = DATE(f2.created))
    OR t1.created is NULL)
GROUP BY DATE , t1.id_store , t1.id_product
```

Comment: All conditions on `t1` should be in `ON` clause.

Comment: Tks Nikola.. I put id_store and id_product in ON clause and worked..

Answer (score 0):

That record cannot be displayed (obviously) because you are filtering out stores only with ID of 3. The RIGHT JOIN does what it's supposed to do, then then you're further reducing results with the filter. I think you'll have to handle this in your main code to add the "missing" records for you. I don't think SQL can do what you want it to do.

Comment: Sure it can. You need to put conditions in `ON` clause.